# Can't connect to internet via terminal while browser can

Tags: terminal, ping

I can't connect to internet using the terminal but the browser works properly!
I'm able to write this message with Firefox but the terminal isn't able even to ping Google:

```
$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (216.58.212.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9004ms
```

I'm running CentOS7 and I have no clue about how to solve (my final goal is install a package via yum).

**.: Edit :.**

There is no proxy, I can ping the gateway and I have no control over the firewall.

Comment: Does your browser use a proxy ?

Comment: Hello! Please give more info about your situation: routes table, maybe proxy, gateway parameters ...

Comment: No proxy, I can ping the gateway and I have no control over the firewall.

Comment: @Theophrastus yes, but IT guys told me that they changed nothing and they have no idea about the reason of my problem.